# Swift NaturalLanguage framework error “Token SequenceType length is 0"

Tags: swift, xcode, nlp, swift4.2, createml

I’m currently using Apple’s CreateML to generate a NLP model from a JSON file I have. Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import CreateML
import NaturalLanguage

let trainingData = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Fel", withExtension: "json")!)
let model = try MLWordTagger(trainingData: trainingData, tokenColumn: "tokens", labelColumn: "labels")
let metadata = MLModelMetadata(author: "Sai Kambampati", shortDescription: "The Felicity Named Entity Recognizer", license: "MIT", version: "1.0")
try model.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/SaiKambampati/Desktop/Felicity.mlmodel"), metadata: metadata)
```

The JSON file has 116,096 lines and Xcode was able to parse it correctly. It generated a validation set from 5% of the data. However, when it began tokenizing the data and extracting features, I got an error saying:

`▿ MLCreateError
  ▿ generic : 1 element
    - reason : "Token SequenceType length is 0”`

I have no idea what this means and can’t find anything online! Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file must be in this format to work with MLWordTagger's tokenColumn param. Tokens as a list of strings and labels as a list of string.

```
[
    {
      "tokens": [
        "Aprender",
        "a",
        "realizar",
        "Aquisição",
        "de",
        "usuários"
      ],
      "labels": [
        "GENERIC_ACTION",
        "NONE",
        "ACTION",
        "TOPIC",
        "NONE",
        "NONE"
      ]
    }, ...
```

Comment: I had this issue when one of my `token` arrays was empty.